# How do I replace NULL values with string using COALESCE function?

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to put 'unassigned' to the null values using coalesce function within the select statement.
Here is the code:

````
SELECT ORDER_ID, ORDER_DATE,
coalesce (SALES_REP_ID,'NA') REP
FROM ORDERS```
[But having error "inconsistent datatype"]
How do I fix it?

[Data, in which sales_rep_id have null values which i want to change it to 'unassigned']
````

Comment: you need to edit your question, show the complete table DDL, sample data, and expected output,

Comment: `SALES_REP_ID` sounds like a numerical datatype, you should cast it to a string in the `COALESCE`

Comment: @HoneyBadger not sure how to fix it.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2):

As the error mentions, you are mixing data types. Inside the `coalesce` function you need to convert sales_rep_id to a varchar first.

```
SELECT ORDER_ID, ORDER_DATE,
coalesce (to_char(SALES_REP_ID), 'NA') REP
FROM ORDERS
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you don't mix data types

```
SELECT ORDER_ID, ORDER_DATE,
       case when SALES_REP_ID is null 
            then 'NA'
            else to_char(SALES_REP_ID)
       end REP
FROM ORDERS
```

Comment: is it possible using coalesce, as i was trying to do that way and wanted to fix that way.
This is also correct the way you represented now.